# Как представить плоские геометрические объекты в виде вектора чтобы подать на вход искусственной нейронной сети?

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, геометрия

У меня есть коллекция плоских геометрических объектов, прямоугольников (количество не фиксировано). Они расположены на координатной плоскости, координаты и размеры доступны. Как преобразовать все эти данные в форму, который можно представить на вход искусственной нейронной сети.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще прямоугольник ABCD можно описать в виде вектора, который собственно говоря будет его диагональю. Начало вектора это вершина A с известными координатами, а точка С конец вектора.

Comment: А как решить проблему количества, вить на вход нейронной сети необходима передать фиксирование количество цифер?

Comment: Количество прямоугольников у тебя не фиксировано, но количество данных ( координаты ) у тебя для каждого прямоугольника будет фиксировано же?

Comment: Да но этого не достаточно, необходимо передавать сразу все прямоугольники.

Comment: А что должна анализировать нейронка? Расположение прямоугольников? Или суммарную прощадь? Или еще что то?

Comment: Ну передавайте на вход вектор из прямоугольников, каждый из которых задан диагональю. Вектор конечный, его сеть примет.

Comment: Если нет дополнительных ограничений, например, что стороны параллельны осям координат, то одной диагонали недостаточно.